# Load template from a standalone bokeh server

Tags: python, bokeh

Looking at the [bokeh dash example](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/app/dash) `bokeh serve` loads the jinja2 template at the following location *"./templates/index.html"*.

How can I do that when starting bokeh from my main as a standalone using `import bokeh.server.server`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Bokeh v0.12.6 this would be:

```
import numpy as np
import webbrowser
from flask import Flask, render_template
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from bokeh.application import Application
from bokeh.application.handlers import FunctionHandler
from bokeh.embed import autoload_server
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Slider
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.server.server import Server

app = Flask(__name__)

def make_doc(doc):

    def get_plot():
        x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
        y = np.log(x) * np.sin(x)
        source = ColumnDataSource(data = dict(x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000), y = y))

        plot = figure()
        plot.line('x', 'y', source = source)
        return plot

    doc.add_root(get_plot())
    doc.title = "Time Plot"

bokeh_app = Application(FunctionHandler(make_doc))

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET'])
def bkapp_page():
    script = autoload_server(model = None, url = 'http://localhost:5006/appname')
    return render_template("index.html", script = script)

def bk_worker():
    server = Server({'/appname': bokeh_app}, io_loop = IOLoop(), allow_websocket_origin = ["localhost:{}".format(8080)])
    server.start()
    server.io_loop.start()

from threading import Thread
Thread(target = bk_worker).start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Opening single process Flask app with embedded Bokeh application on http://localhost:{}/'.format(8080))
    webbrowser.open_new("http://localhost:{}/".format(8080))
    app.run(port = 8080, debug = False)
```

For the latest v1.0.4 replace the autoload_server() function with server_document().
The result is as follows:
[image]

Comment: Just a word, I think you don't really need Flask to do this. I've been able to deploy my own app with my custom theme.yaml as shown in the official doc:
https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/branch-2.3/examples/howto/server_embed/standalone_embed.py